# Python virtual environment created not coming in Jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter

I am creating virtual environments in Python using `virtualenv`, with the command
`virtualenv env_name` and activating in the Linux terminal using `source env_name/bin/activate`.

But the virtual environment I created is not automatically visible in the `jupyter notebook` kernels. What should I do to make these environments access through Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Did you launch the notebook *inside* the shell where you activated the virtual environment?

Comment: I tried opening jupyter-notebook inside the activated environment and in the native environment. It's not coming in both cases.

Comment: please share the error if any. Try `jupyter notebook` from inside the shell where you activated the virtualenv

Comment: There's no error to show. Its just the kernel name of the environment created is not coming in Jupyter notebook. I tried it. But it's not working @knownUnknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite trivial only.
We just need to add one more line in command for adding the kernel into the python. Say, I'm creating a new environment `av`

#### creating environment

```
virtualenv av
```

#### adding the kernel to ipython

```
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=av
```

This will give an output

```
Installed kernelspec av in /Users/sreekiran/Library/Jupyter/kernels/av
```

And voila!

[image: output]

I got the solution thanks to this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/create-virtual-environment-using-virtualenv-and-add-it-to-jupyter-notebook-6e1bf4e03415).